# How to get the last line in simple string variable - C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a simple string variable as follows and I want to get last line from this text.

```
string mytext ="line1\nline2\nline3";
```

Please do not offer to use

```
var lastLine = File.ReadLines("file.txt").Last();
```

Because the target string is not stored in the file.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split by newline and then do last:

```
var lastLine = mytext.Split('\n').Last();
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
int idx = mytext.LastIndexOf('\n');

if (idx != -1)
{
    var rsult = mytext.Substring(idx + 1);
}
```

Comment: This is the only reasonable solution. The others are painfully inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        string mytext ="line1\nline2\nline3";
        string lastLine = mytext.Split('\n').Last();
        Console.WriteLine(lastLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

Simply split the string and get the value on last index.

```
string [] lines = mytext.Split('\n');
lines[2];   // This will you your result
```

Comment: string [] lines = mytext.Split(“\n”); is not possible in C#, you either can give string[] or char[]. "\n" is just a string and not accepted.